# Can I have a different Extension method for IEnumerable<T> than for <T>?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have an extension method that works on any class, but I want to call a special version if I am working on `IEnumerable<T>`.

For Example

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{

    public static dynamic Test<T>(this T source)
    {   
        dynamic expandoObject = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
        var dictionary = (IDictionary<string,object>)expandoObject;

        dictionary["Test"] = source.ToString();

        return dictionary;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> Test<T>(this List<T> source)
    {
        var result = new List<dynamic>();
        foreach(var r in source)
            yield return r.Test();          
    }


    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> Test<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        var result = new List<dynamic>();
        foreach(var r in source)
            yield return r.Test();          
    }
}
```

// Usage

```
public class X 
{
    string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}


void Main()
{
    List<X> list = new List<X>() { new X() };

    list.Test().Dump();                     // Correct but only works because there is an explicit overload for List<T>

    var array = list.ToArray();
    ((IEnumerable<X>) array).Test().Dump(); // Correct

     array.Test().Dump(); // Calls the wrong extension method
}
```

Is there any way I can get array.Test() to call the IEnumerable version without having to explicitly cast it?

Alternatively, if I give the extension method different names, if there any way I can get a compiler error if I accidently use the wrong one?

Comment: array inherits from IEnumerable?

Comment: You can try `AsEnumerable()`, but it's just a nicest and shortest way to cast to an `IEnumerable`:

    `array.AsEnumerable().Test();`

Comment: Arrays implement `IEnumerable<T>` but the implementation is added at run time and that is why the "wrong" extension method is called.

Comment: Possibel duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208101/call-generic-extension-method-with-a-dynamic-type

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to solve it in a wrong direction. The List implements IEnumerable interface and as such the compiler can have problem with solving the best method will be invoked on List. What you could do -- you could test if the IEnumerable is a list inside the extension method.

```
public static IEnumerable<dynamic> Test<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (source is List<T>) {
        // here 
    }
    var result = new List<dynamic>();
    foreach(var r in source)
        yield return r.Test();          
}
```

Comment: I don't want a different version for List<T> vs IEnumerable<T>. I just added the List<T> version to show that if I create an explicit overload for List<T> it will be correctly called. If I created an explicit overload for T[] it would work for arrays, but I can't create an explicit overload for every possible class that implements IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: Sorry of course I meant you could test the source for being an array 
`if (sourse is T[])`

Comment: Still misses the point that the IEnumerable<T> extension method is not called  .

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `T` and not rely on type inference, this will hint compiler to use correct extension method. Code would look like this:

```
var array = list.ToArray();
array.Test<X>().Dump();
```

What happens is, that compiler cannot tell which extension to use, since `Array` is valid argument for both method signatures:

```
public static dynamic Test<T>(this T source) { .. }

public static IEnumerable<dynamic> Test<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) { .. }
```

In first case compiler can assume `T` is of type `Array`. Because of it, compiler has to picks one (might be first defined?).

Comment: That would work, but it doesn't force T to be specified and hence will still compile incorrect code.

Comment: You are correct, sadly I don't know if compile it is possible to achieve compile time error in this case. But you can add another extension method, like mentioned as mentioned in answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Add this extension method to explicitly catch all array types:

```
public static IEnumerable<dynamic> Test<T>(this T[] source)
{
    var result = new List<dynamic>();
    foreach(var r in source)
        yield return r.Test();          
}
```